# Single role multiple IP addresses in Spring Security configuration

Tags: java, security, spring-boot, spring-security, ip-address

In my Spring Boot project I am trying to give access to several admin users with specific IP address.

**Is it possible to map a single role to multiple IP addresses?**

Here is the code from my security configuration which didn't work. (I am giving hard coded role name and ip addresses for simplicity)

```
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<String> ipAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
        ipAddresses.add("127.0.0.1");
        ipAddresses.add("192.168.1.0/24");
        ipAddresses.add("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1");

        for (String ip : ipAddresses) {
            http.authorizeRequests().
                    antMatchers("/admin" + "/**")
                    .access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('" + ip + "')");
        }
    }

    //some other configurations
}
```

URL of my request: http://localhost:9595/admin/checkappeals/211

Comment: I am getting the following error: HTTP Status 403 -message- description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `for` loop results in following configuration:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1')");
    }

    //some other configurations
}
```

So for URL:

```
http://localhost:9595/admin/checkappeals/211
```

only the first matcher is considered, see [HttpSecurity#authorizeRequests](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests--):

> Note that the matchers are considered in order. Therefore, the following is invalid because the first matcher matches every request and will never get to the second mapping:
>
> ```java
> http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").antMatchers("/admin/**")
>             .hasRole("ADMIN")
> ```

You have to build something like:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").acces("hasRole('admin') and (hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24') or hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1'))";
```

Comment: Very weirdly on the day this has been posted I'm having the same issue. Do you know of any way to get this working as a list? My issue is that there are an unknown number of IP addresses that need to be authorised (which will be read from a config file) so the solution where each IP is inside the access param doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @haddow64: Use a StringBuilder (or something similar) and concatinate the conditions in a for loop. The complete condition use like `antMatchers("/admin/**").access(condition)`.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can join your comma separated ips into an expression for the .access() method:

```
private String createHasIpRangeExpression() {

    String ipRanges= "127.0.0.1,192.168.1.0/24,0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
    List<String> validIps = Arrays.asList(ipRanges.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    String hasIpRangeAccessExpresion = validIps.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.joining("') or hasIpAddress('", "hasIpAddress('","')"));
    return hasIpRangeAccessExpresion;
}
```