# Spring Security Java Configuration: How to combine requirements via logical or?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have a webapplication based on spring boot that should be secured via http basic auth except the request is send from a specific IP address.

I am able to set-up both configurations for themselves but not combined via or.

**IP Filter**

```
private String allowedIp = "123.456.789.123/32";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasIpAddress(allowedIp);
```

or

**HTTP Basic Auth**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(cncAuthEntryPoint);
}
```

**How can I combine these two configurations?**

I am using

- Spring 5.0.4,
- Spring Boot 2.0.0, and
- Spring Security 5.0.3.

Do you need any addtional information?

Comment: Hi, what about some SPEL ? 
http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .access("isAuthenticated() or hasIpAddress('X.X.X.X')")
               .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(cncAuthEntryPoint)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring security multiple hasIPAddress antMatchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303097/spring-security-multiple-hasipaddress-antmatchers)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304683/5277820

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single role multiple IP addresses in Spring Security configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302809/single-role-multiple-ip-addresses-in-spring-security-configuration)