# Spring: Serve different paths on different ports

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Spring-boot web application running on Tomcat, apache server. On production environment I want to expose the custom monitoring view

```
localhost:8080/myapp/custom-monitor-html-stuff
```

To everyone in the company without exposing rest of the application's endpoints. This custom monitoring is different than the Spring actuator which I use, which already runs on a different port.

Using Spring, tomcat or apache configuration. Is there a way to serve different paths on different ports? So I can take security measures by the port number. If not what do you suggest? If nothing works probably I will need to separate the monitoring frontend code from the api, put it in a separate war, so can serve however I like.

Comment: Like actuator endpoints you can protect certain paths with authentication. If you only care about ports then you might want to use a strategy like here for your antmatchers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302809/single-role-multiple-ip-addresses-in-spring-security-configuration

Comment: You can also use Spring discovery and Zuul for achieving this. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Comment: @Yogi I dont have microservice nor using spring cloud