# Role based security in spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm having a usecase where I have to restrict users with some role instead of url-pattern to a fixed set of ip addresses. For example: A user with super-admin role can access only from ip-addresses 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 etc.
I have to implement it on both authentication as well as on authorization.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like below code by adding hasRole and hasIpAddress methods.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1')");
        }

    }
```

Full post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304683/6572971