# Spring boot whitelist ip range

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ip, whitelist

most of the online tutorials focus on anyway secured endpoints, where IP whitelisting comes on top. So most of them describe:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeCustom implements AuthenticationProvider {

    // initialization of ipWhitelistRange

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) {
        WebAuthenticationDetails details = 
                           (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
        String userIp = details.getRemoteAddress();
        if(!ipWhitelistRange.contains(userIp)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid IP Address");
        }

        return authentication;      
    }
}
```

then the above should be added to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SomeSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private SomeCustom authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My use case is that I am having a fully open endpoint defined with a placeholder path variable like `/v1/something/{path}`.
My current `SomeSecurity` is basically just `.anyRequest().permitAll()` and now I want to add the IP range restriction to only one of the `{path}` substitutions. For example:
`/v1/something/foo`, `/v1/something/bar` etc. should remain fully open, just `/v1/something/special` should be restricted to some IP range. Whether it is possible to specify the IP range restriction on a path placeholder or not is not that important, I could specify also a fully new endpoint, my issue is more the fact that I cannot manage to trigger the IP range validation.
When I add the `.authenticated()` my endpoint starts to respond with `Full authentication is required to access this resource` and in DEBUG mode the break point in the IP range validation logic is not stopping.

In other words, how can I trigger the IP range validation of my `SomeCustom` without forcing the client of the API to authenticate with an USER?
I know I could use the `SecurityContext` to get the user's IP and do the validation manually in my service logic or so, but this is not the idea I would say.
Using Spring boot 2.2.x (Spring 5.x)

EDIT: Since I realized that `.authenticated()` will for sure enforce a user login other than ANONYMOUS and since I don't use any login, thus my user is automatically the anonymous one I tried the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/special").hasRole("ANONYMOUS")
      .anyRequest().permitAll()
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/special").anonymous()
      .anyRequest().permitAll()
}
```

both above are just going through without to trigger the `SomeCustom` IP whitelist provider.

Could it be that just a customer auth provider is only triggered when a non-anonymous user is being used?

Comment: Could you show your code? You didn't post the restriction of the IP. There is only an authentication for all requests.

Comment: Thanks @dur for your question. I omitted the code since it is an obvious one, where I check the IP against a set of IPs like `whitelistSet.contains(ip)`, anyway as I mentioned my break point is not even stopping in this method, so it is not triggered at all kind of. I will add for more clarity though.

Comment: I think your code is to complecate. Spring Security already supports it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302809/single-role-multiple-ip-addresses-in-spring-security-configuration

Comment: @dur nice, I had this in mind as a fallback if this is not working, to just add the `hasIpAddress` multiple times. But then why not just using `.addFilterAfter(new IPWhitelistRangeFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)` in my `SomeSecurity`, then in `IPWhitelistRangeFilter` I could do whatever I want and respond with `401` for example. Do I have to consider something special when dealing with a filter at the end of the filter chain?

Comment: Sure, you could use a filter, but in your question is a `AuthenticationProvider` that's not a filter, hence it is not always applied.

Comment: @dur sure got you. So looks like `AuthenticationProvider` can only be used, when anyway some sort of authentication is taking place like `.httpBasic()`. I have to obviously fallback to using `.hasIpAddress()` or a `addFilter()`.
Just now that I dug deeper I realized that `.hasIpAddress()` checks against the `remoteAddr` of the request, which is not reliable at all, since if my code is behind loadbalancer, it will be the IP of the load balancer and not of the client. I don't know why spring folks did not think of it and added a `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header check

Comment: AFAIR you could configure it in your Tomcat configuration.